# Looper.prepare() error inside a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am using handler to get GCM value
I want to update this value in my database

so I call AsyncTask from the handler

but I get this Error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I checked other solutions they said I have to put the code in the run() section which I already do..

This is the code,

```
private void GetGCM(final String UserID) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                GCMHelper gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper(getApplicationContext());
                String gcmRegID = "";
                gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("123456");

                // Update using Web Service
                try {
                    UpdateGCMWSTask updateGCMWSTask = new UpdateGCMWSTask();


                    updateGCMWSTask.execute(UserID, gcmRegID);
                    // ************ HERE IS THE ERROR ***********************

                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite convinced that this particular piece of code needs an explicit background thread at all ...

Comment: i have been trying to do the GCM code for more than 2 weeks and this is the only way that worked for me, now I just want to save the code in the database.

Comment: As I said, I cannot see why, but that maybe a lack of understanding from my part. Where does `GCMHelper` come from and what does it do? It looks like the code tries do something synchronous on the main (UI) thread. But if you already have a worker thread, why the additional `AsyncTask`? Or to but it short: I don't get it, but somehow it looks wrong.

Comment: GCMHelper is a class that gets the GCM code, the 2nd part is to save this code in the database, thats why I use UpdateGCMWSTask  AsyncTask and thats where I get the error

Comment: Ah, I see. The GCM methods are synchronous and you cannot call them on the UI thread because they are blocking. I'd try moving the `run()` block into an `AsyncTask` by itself. If you still need `UpdateGCMWSTask`, run it from `onPostExecute()`. Your custom background thread doesn't have a message looper and I see no need to create one.

Comment: can a thread have a onPostExecute ? i thought it only comes with AsyncTask

Comment: Read again, I'd move everything into an `AsyncTask`, this should probably always be your first choice, as the `AsyncTask` gives you the necessary glue to execute stuff back on the UI thread (and thus with a looper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Looper.prepare()  and  Looper.loop() in you code, like this:

```
private void GetGCM(final String UserID) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Looper.prepare();
                GCMHelper gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper(getApplicationContext());
                String gcmRegID = "";
                gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("123456");

                // Update using Web Service
                try {
                    UpdateGCMWSTask updateGCMWSTask = new UpdateGCMWSTask();


                    updateGCMWSTask.execute(UserID, gcmRegID);
                    // ************ HERE IS THE ERROR ***********************

                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              Looper.loop();
            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create asynctask inside a thread. There are few ways to handle it:

1. Create a new handler.
2. Call function runOnUIThread of activity.
3. Using broadcast.